# Dynamically added view wont fit Pane

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a application with a menu on the left and the view on the right. I have different fxml file. 1 main, and multiple for the view.

Right now I load different view but the view on right doesn't his parent.

**Main view**

```
    <GridPane
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="controller.Controller">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="30.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="70.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <GridPane maxWidth="Infinity" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
          <columnConstraints>
              <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="100.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
              <RowConstraints />
              <RowConstraints />
              <RowConstraints />
              <RowConstraints />
              <RowConstraints />
          </rowConstraints>
          <children>
              <Button fx:id="devices" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Devices" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
              <Button fx:id="inventory" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Inventory" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
          </children>
      </GridPane>
      <Pane
              fx:id="container"
              minWidth="Infinity"
              maxWidth="Infinity"
              GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS"
              GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS"
              GridPane.columnIndex="1"
              GridPane.columnSpan="1"
              GridPane.rowIndex="0">
      </Pane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

**Custom view load in container**

```
<GridPane
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="controller.DevicesController"
        GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS"
        GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">

    <children>
        <TableView
                GridPane.columnIndex="0"
                GridPane.columnSpan="1"
                GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS"
                GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS"
                GridPane.rowIndex="0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text="Devices" />
                <TableColumn text="C2" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

**Current form**[image]

**Controller**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Pane container;
    @FXML private Button devices;
    @FXML private Button inventory;

    private HashMap<Views, Node> views;

    private enum Views {
        DEVICES,
        INVENTORY
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            views = new HashMap<>();

            views.put(Views.DEVICES, FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/" + "view-devices.fxml")));
            views.put(Views.INVENTORY, FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/" + "view-inventory.fxml")));

            devices.setOnMouseClicked(v -> load(Views.DEVICES));
            inventory.setOnMouseClicked(v -> load(Views.INVENTORY));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void load(Views view){
        if (views.containsKey(view)) {
            Node newView = views.get(view);

            if (!container.getChildren().contains(newView)) {
                container.getChildren().add(newView);
            } else {
                newView.resize(container.getMaxWidth(), container.getMaxHeight());
                newView.toFront();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: key not found in map");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to the right view to fit the container.

Comment: Try `fillWidth="true"` on the second `ColumnConstraints` object in the main FXML file.

Comment: I test it, still not working.

Comment: Ah, I guess the grid pane defined in the second FXML file is filling the column in the main grid pane, but the table is not filling the grid pane in the second FXML file? Can you just make the `TableView` the root of the second FXML file? Or maybe add `GridPane.fillWidth="true"` to the `TableView` (as well as the previous `fillWidth`). You seem to have some unnecessary layers here (specifically the second grid pane).

Comment: Still not, I will update with a screen capture.

Comment: Oh, you even have another layer there. Your `TableView` is inside a `GridPane`, which is inside a `Pane`, which is inside a `GridPane`. With the exception of the topmost `GridPane`, each container has only one child (so its redundant). In particular, since `Pane` performs no layout, it can't make the `GridPane` containing the `TableView` grow. You should eliminate some of those redundant layers, especially the `Pane`. It's not really easy to show how, without at least seeing the main controller.

Comment: I update with the controller, but I put the view on the left with my `Pane` so if remove it, how can I do the same without ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pane` you are using for the container for the right side of the display performs no layout, so it cannot make the content fill the available space (no matter what settings you use).

Use a `BorderPane` for the container instead:

```xml
  <BorderPane 
          fx:id="container"
          GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS"
          GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS"
          GridPane.columnIndex="1"
          GridPane.columnSpan="1"
          GridPane.rowIndex="0">
  </BorderPane>
```

and then in the controller you can simply set the new content as the center each time:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private BorderPane container;

    // ...

    public void load(Views view){
        if (views.containsKey(view)) {
            Node newView = views.get(view);
            container.setCenter(newView);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: key not found in map");
        }
    }

}
```